# Periodically call to a web service in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(sliderUpdate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)sliderUpdate:(id)sender
{
    int currentTime = (int)((newPlayer.currentTime.value)/newPlayer.currentTime.timescale);
    slider.value=currentTime;
    NSLog(@"%i",currentTime);
    song.currentTime=currentTime;
    int currentPoint=(int)((newPlayer.currentTime.value)/newPlayer.currentTime.timescale);
    int pointMins=(int)(currentPoint/60);
    int pointSec=(int)(currentPoint%60);
    NSString *strMinlabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",pointMins,pointSec];
    lblSlidermin.text=strMinlabel;
    song.strslidermin=strMinlabel;
}
```

What I want to do, is, in each and every 45 seconds, call a web service:

Example: 1st call in 45 seconds, second in 90 seconds, etc.

How can I do this in this NSTimer?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify your NSTimer for 45 seconds:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:45 target:self selector:@selector(sliderUpdate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```